# Pass ng-repeat variable in html directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

My $scope variable is:

```
$scope.content = [{name:"data1", ap_name:"api1"},
               {name:"data1", ap_name:"api1"},
               {name:"data1", ap_name:"api1"}]
```

My html is

```
<div class="contatiner" ng-repeat="data in content">
    <chart chartdata="data.ap_name"></chart>
</div>
```

I want to append a string to the data what I am passing in chartdata. it should appear as:

```
<chart chartdata="dataapi1"></chart>
```

Any idea how can I do it? I cont want to make changes in scope variable, I am doing this intentionally.

Assume I have set scope in directive and chart directive is all good.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenation your additional string `your_model + 'additional string'`

```
chartdata="data.ap_name + 'additional string'"
```

And in your directive you will get it by

```
scope : {
  chartdata : '=' // it is equivalent to '=chartdata'
  ...
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ePUhTIqiiImwu3b4ifYM?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I tried, doesnt seems to be working. Can you upload an example?

Comment: Great example, your answer should be selected as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@` in directive definition code.

For example:

In your directive code:

```
scope : {
  chartdata : '@chartdata'
  ...
},
controller : function ($scope) {
  // $scope.chartdata should be a string
}
```

In your html:

```
<div class="contatiner" ng-repeat="data in content">
    <chart chartdata="{{data.ap_name}}"></chart>
</div>
```

Comment: No that is not what I want. I have chartdata: '=chartdata' because in the scope I am sending the object to my chart directive from my controller.